# Showing alert when custom Keyboard is enabled?

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

For security reasons, we want to show alert if custom Keyboard is enabled for Login fields.  If i use the following code

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier
{   
    if ([extensionPointIdentifier isEqualToString: UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier])
   {
        return NO;
   }
     return YES;
}
```

If i use the following code,it disables keyboard in all fields.But i want to disable to few fields only.  Tried to keep alert  inside the if loop but it displays alert for every keyboard.  How can i Achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

Apple does not allow the use of custom keyboard for protected fields such as Login. To do so, just tick the box "secure text entry" of your textfield

[image: secure text field]

Have a look here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html

Comment: This method can also be used to make sure that a UITextInput only uses the system keyboard. This may be handy in a VNC application with a hidden text field or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

`application:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:` method is triggered for every textfield in the application. In your code, there is no condition to check for a particular textfield to be enabled or disabled.

To implement this functionality, you have to get the reference of the tapped textfield from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` and after that use the reference inside `application:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:` to enable or disable the custom keyboard.